# shell script : write entire contents of for loop to file, not only last line

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array in a shell script with index and value . I am able to print this array. How do i write the entire array into a text file?

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}" >outfile
done
```

However, only the last element of the array is present in `outfile`. How can I fix this?

Comment: The code works fine. How do i redirect the whole array on to a file

Comment: The same way you redirect *anything* to a file, with `>`.

Comment: When i direct it that way, It is only storing the last value.

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer is to put the redirection after the `done`, not on the `printf`:

```
for key in "${!array[@]}"; do
  value=${array[$key]}
  [[ $key = *[$'\t\n']* ]] && continue    # security: disallow keys with tabs or newlines
  [[ $value = *[$'\n']* ]] && continue    # security: disallow values with newlines
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}"
done >outfile
```

Note those checks -- I'm not doing them again later in this code, but they're necessary to allow a value in your format to inject other key/value pairs, or to allow "values" to actually specify other keys.

---

That said, to replace an entire file *at once*, one should use a write-and-rename pattern to ensure atomicity. The general pattern is:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp outfile.XXXXXX)
write_your_data >"$tempfile"
mv -- "$tempfile" outfile
```

`write_your_data` need not be a placeholder -- it could also be a function encapsulating the loop itself:

```
write_your_data() {
  local i
  for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, the reason you are only seeing the last line is because you are using `>` instead of `>>`.

`>` redirects the output to a file, either creating it or overwriting what was already there.

`>>` also redirects the output, but appends to a file...adding it to the end of it.

Every time your `for` loop iterated, you were "recreating" the file.

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}" >> outfile
done
```

Comment: Using `>>` on individual `printf` or `echo` calls is inefficient: It re-opens the file before writing each single line, and closes it again after. That's a whole bunch of `open()`s and `close()`s (and thus, implicitly, flushes) that would be avoided if you opened the file only once and reused that handle.

Comment: True, I was simply answering the question of why he was only seeing the last line using the code given by the OP, and how he could modify the code very simply to achieve the desired results.